# lstlisting R keywords

Tags: listings, r

I want to write R source code in my latex file so I'm using the listings package.

The problem is that I want R keywords to appear in blue but for instance a variable named abc.log.de appears with log in blue. I don't want that to happen if log is part of a larger variable name in R. (Example bellow)

How should I proceed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
language=R,
aboveskip=3mm,
belowskip=3mm,
showstringspaces=false,
columns=flexible,
numbers=none,
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
stringstyle=\color{mauve},
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=true,
tabsize=3
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
L.V2<-log(V2)
dados.log<-dados
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks! I've edited the question with a MWE. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, the [R markup](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.dtx) in the listings package regards the period `.` as an *[other](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)* (i.e., non-letter) type of character, along with `_` and `$`, which allows to recognize keywords that include them (such as `data.frame`). However, this also meansthat variables defined in the form `foo.keyword.bar` will highlight the keyword between the periods.

You can prevent this behaviour by specifying the period `.` as a letter character in the listings markup, by adding `alsoletter={.}` in `\lstset`. Unfortunately, this will also prevent other keywords containing periods (such as `data.frame` or `read.csv`) from being highlighted.

Alternatively, you could name your variables differently in your code (*e.g.*, `dados.ln`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\lstset{frame=tb,
language=R,
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
alsoletter={.}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
L.V2<-log(V2)
dados.log<-dados
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Two minor points:

- In your minimal working example, don't forget `\documentclass{article}`.
- You don't need to show all the settings in a *minimal* working example.